# Copying headers of red text to another range

Tags: excel, vba

Goal: Have the column header of any text in red be represented in column F of the same row as the text.

Problem: Code currently references active row, and for some reason copies F2 (which is written in red). I know the code currently would be attempting to copy/paste over a cell a few times, and I'll work that out later.

```
Sub CopyRed()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("G3:BF900")

    For Each row In rng.Rows
        For Each cell In row.Cells
            If cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column).Copy
            Range("F" & (ActiveCell.row)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If
        Next cell
    Next row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I follow your logic. Your problem is that you reference active cell but you are not defining it or changing it other than through the pasting. I think you mean to reference `cell` (?)

```
Sub CopyRed()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("G3:BF900")

For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells
        If cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Cells(2, cell.Column).Copy Range("F" & cell.row)
        End If
    Next cell
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This will do. You couldnt follow my logic because I'm not great at this and it was clearly flawed, lol.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. It could be me, the brain is definitely softening.

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing the active cell, so the copy command is always called on row 2 of the active cell, which much be in the F column. I changed the code below to fix the issue.

```
Sub CopyRed()
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim row As Range
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' this should be improved to point at the correct worksheet by name

   Set rng = ws.Range("G3:BF900")

   For Each row In rng.Rows
         For Each cell In row.Cells
            If cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                cell.Copy
                ws.Range("F" & (cell.row)).PasteSpecial
            End If
         Next cell
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a Compile error: Method or data member not found error when I run this, highlighting the .rng from Set ws.rng =

Comment: My mistake, the ws. should go in front of the Range method